# How do you access your chartjs chart in angular

Tags: angular, chart.js

So I want to apply things like chart.update() and chart.clear() but not sure how to do this with angular? What is my html template and ts file meant to look like to be able to access these chartjs properties?

I have added a @viewchild decorator to a baseChartDirective

Something like `@viewchild (baseChartDirective) chart?: baseChartDirective`

But this returns undefined when printing contents of chart `console.log(this.chart)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `HTML` template, declare nothing but the `canvas`. The Chart should be created inside the component class, after Angular has completed initialization of the component's view. A suitable method for this is [`ngAfterViewInit()`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit).

*HTML Template*

```
<canvas #canvas></canvas>
```

*Component class*

```
export class ChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('canvas') canvasRef: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  chart: Chart;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     const canvas = this.canvasRef.nativeElement;
     chart = new Chart(canvas, {
       // chart config
     });
  }
```

It should then be possible to call `chart.update()` and other functions on `chart`.

To make your work easier, you could however also use [`ng2-charts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts) and take a look at its [Stackblitz Starting Templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts#stackblitz-starting-templates).

Comment: unminder's response works for the most part, but the following documentation provides more explanation of ng2-charts in case anyone encounters the same issue! https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/